# Correspondence between rotations and pairs of antipodal unit quaternions

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I'm having some trouble understanding how rotations of $\mathbb{R}^3$ correspond to antipodal pairs of unit quaternions.

In section 1.5 of his *Naive Lie Theory*, John Stillwell proves the theorem that conjugation by $\cos \theta + u \sin \theta$, where $u$ is a purely imaginary unit quaternion, results in a rotation of the purely imaginary quaternions by $2 \theta$ about $u$.

He then says that

> This theorem shows that every rotation of $\mathbb{R}^3$, given by an axis $u$ and angle of rotation $\alpha$, is the result of conjugation by the unit quaternion
>   $$t = \cos \frac{\alpha}{2} + u \sin \frac{\alpha}{2}.$$
>   The same rotation is induced by $-t$, since $(-t)^{-1}s(-t) = t^{-1}st$. But $\pm t$ are the *only* unit quaternions that induce this rotation, because each unit quaternion is uniquely expressible in the form $t = \cos \frac{\alpha}{2} + u \sin \frac{\alpha}{2}$, and the rotation is uniquely determined by the two (axis, angle) pairs $(u, \alpha)$ and $(-u, -\alpha)$. The quaternions $t$ and $-t$ are said to be *antipodal*, because they represent diametrically opposite points on the 3-sphere of unit quaternions.
>
> Thus the theorem says that *rotations of $\mathbb{R}^3$ correspond to antipodal pairs of unit quaternions*.

I don't understand what Stillwell means when he says that "each unit quaternion is uniquely expressible in the form $t = \cos \frac{\alpha}{2} + u \sin \frac{\alpha}{2}$"? Indeed, this seems to be *false*, since
$$\cos \frac{\alpha}{2} + u \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} = \cos \frac{-\alpha}{2} + (-u) \sin \frac{-\alpha}{2}, \tag{*}$$
but $\alpha \neq -\alpha$ and $u \neq -u$.

I also don't understand what he means by "the rotation is uniquely determined by the two (axis, angle) pairs $(u, \alpha)$ and $(-u, -\alpha)$". Surely only one of these is sufficient to determine the rotation in question?

I also note that on the Wikipedia page for [Quaternions and spatial rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#The_hypersphere_of_rotations), it is stated that the fact each rotation is represented by two distinct unit quaternions

> reflects the fact that each rotation can be represented as a rotation about some axis, or, equivalently, as a negative rotation about an axis pointing in the opposite direction (a so-called double cover).

This confuses me since this "double cover" property of rotations seems to correspond more to $(*)$ than to the fact that conjugation by $-t$ gives the same rotation as conjugation by $t$. Indeed, writing

$$ \begin{align}
-t &= -\cos \frac{\alpha}{2} - u \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} \\
&= \cos(\frac{\alpha}{2} + \pi) + u \sin(\frac{\alpha}{2} + \pi) \\
&= \cos \frac{\alpha + 2 \pi}{2} + u \sin \frac{\alpha + 2 \pi}{2}
\end{align}$$

it appears $-t$ corresponds to the rotation $(u, \alpha + 2 \pi)$ rather than $(-u, -\alpha)$ as intimated by this remark. (I say this somewhat metaphorically -- I am aware that as objects $(u, \alpha + 2 \pi)$ and $(-u, -\alpha)$ are in fact identical.)

How does this correspondence actually work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stillwell is being a little sloppy here. When we say that a complex number is $r e^{i\theta}$, we're being a little informal, since it's also $(-r) e ^{i (\theta + \pi)}$ ... but we all agree to use only positive $r$, and to treat $z = 0$ as a special case, and at THAT point, the $(r, \theta)$ description is unique. Something similar is going on here.

I believe that the uniqueness he's claiming is that every unit quaternion 
$$
q = a + bi + cj + dk
$$
can be uniquely expressed as 
$$
q = \cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) \mathbf u
$$
for some unit quaternions $\mathbf u$ and for some $\theta$ between $0$ and $\pi$. To get this represention, we write
$$
\theta = \arccos(a),
$$
compute $e = \sin(\theta)$, and write 
$$
\mathbf u = (b/e, c/e, d/e).
$$

He then says (to himself), "Oh, and to make things simpler later on, let's write $\alpha = 2 \theta$, so $\alpha$ is between $0$ and $2 \pi$.

As for "The rotation is uniquely determined the the two axis-angle pairs...", that's a bit sloppy, too. What's meant is, I think, this:

"Each of the two axis-angle pairs *blah* and *blah* determines the same rotation, and furthermore, there's no other axis-angle pair that corresponds to this rotation: the map from axis-angle pairs to rotations is 2-to-1, and surjective."

But here's the fact: the unit quaternions $q$ and $-q$ really do correspond to the same rotation. A 2-to-1 mapping like this (with a few other properties, all of which this map has!) is called a "double cover".

I'm going to go all out and illustrate this for you by looking at the unit quaternions of the form 
$$
a = a + 0i + 0j + bk
$$
which happen to correspond to rotations of the xy-plane of 3-space (or "the ij plane of pure vector quaternion space")

Each such quaternion is expressible as 
$$
q = \cos(\theta) + \mathbf k \sin(\theta)
$$
for some theta between $0$ and $2 \pi$. Let's look at the map 
$$
s \mapsto q^{-1} s q
$$
on the pure vector quaternions. We can see what it does to each of $s = i, j, k$. I'll let you check that $q^{-1} k q = k$. So it's a rotation about the $k$ axis. Let's see by how much:
\begin{align}
q^{-1} i q 
&= (a - bk) i (a + bk)\\
&= (ai - bj)(a + bk)\\
&= a^2 i - ab j + ab (-j) - b^2 jk \\
&= (a^2 - b^2) i - 2ab j 
\end{align}
where $a = \cos \theta$ and $b = \sin \theta$. By the double-angle formulas, we have $a^2 - b^2 = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta = \cos 2\theta$ and $2ab = \sin 2 \theta$.

Summary so far: the great circle of unit quaternions in the $(1,k)$ plane each corresponds to a rotation of the pure vector quaternions in the $ij$ plane, with
$\cos \theta + k \sin \theta$ corresponding to a rotation by $2 \theta$.

Each quaternion in this great circle corresponds to a rotation, but clearly, two opposite quaternions (for, say, $\theta$ and $\theta + \pi$) correspond to the same rotation of the $ij$-plane (by amount $2 \theta$, or equivalently, by $2\theta + 2 \pi$).

Does that help any?

Answer (score 0):

You can display this from the matrix side of things by invoking Euler's theorem of rigid-body rotations [1]. It states that the orientation of a body after having undergone any sequence of rotations is equivalent to a single rotation by the unit vector $\vec{n}=(n_x,n_y,n_z)^{\top}$. So for a given rotation;
\begin{align}R  = \begin{bmatrix}r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} \\ r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} \\ r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} \end{bmatrix} \qquad (1) \end{align}
We have the equivalent representation;
\begin{align}
R(\vec{n},\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)+n_{x}^2(1-\cos(\theta)) & n_xn_y(1-c)-n_zs & n_xn_z(1-\cos(\theta))+n_y\sin(\theta) \\ n_yn_x(1-\cos(\theta)) + n_z\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)+n_y^2(1-\cos(\theta)) & n_yn_z(1-\cos(\theta)) + n_x\sin(\theta) \\ n_zn_x(1-\cos(\theta))-n_y\sin(\theta) & n_zn_y(1-\cos(\theta)) + n_x\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)+n_z^2(1-\cos(\theta)) \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Now what is not obvious from inspection is the following change of variables, let $\vec{e} = (e_0, e_1, e_2, e_3)$;
\begin{align}e_0 &= \cos(\theta/2) \\ e_1 &= n_x\sin(\theta/2) \\ e_2 &= n_y\sin(\theta/2) \\ e_3 &= n_z\sin(\theta/2) \end{align}
These are known as $\it{Euler~parameters}.$ From an algebraic point of view we have effectively formed a double covering of the space of rotations. Our equivalent representation $R(\vec{n},\theta)$ that we defined earlier can now be expressed as;
\begin{align}
R(e_0, e_1, e_2, e_3) = \begin{bmatrix} 2(e_0^2 + e_1^2)-1 & 2(e_1e_2-e_0e_3) & 2(e_1e_3+e_0e_2) \\ 2(e_1e_2-e_0e_3) & 2(e_0^2 + e_2^2)-1 & 2(e_1e_3-e_0e_1) \\ 2(e_1e_3-e_0e_2) & 2(e_2e_3+e_0e_1) & 2(e_0^2 + e_2^3)-1
 \end{bmatrix} \qquad (2)
\end{align}
From inspection we now see that $\vec{e}$ and $-\vec{e}$ both represent the same rotation matrix. Computationally however we have to solve the system of non-linear equations by setting our original matrix $(1)$ equal to the matrix we arrived at $(2)$.

[1] *Goldstein, Herbert*, Classical mechanics, Cambridge: Addison-Wesley Press, Inc. XII, 399 pp. (1951). [ZBL0043.18001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0043.18001).